# How to get XML response instead of string using Amazon MWS Reports API operation GetReport?

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I am getting a string response from Amazon MWS Report API operation GetReport.
All I want to get the response in XML. Is there a way?

Comment: Hi @worrybeast, did you solve your problem? I have the same issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40897899/parse-amazon-mws-results-to-json-or-xml)

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your amazon seller account to generate reports in XML format, as mentioned in this snippet from
   http://amazonpayments.s3.amazonaws.com/documents/Managing_Orders_with_MWS_APIs_en_US.pdf

```
2.3.2 Report Formats
Whether a seller receives reports in XML or flat-file format is 
determined by the seller account
configuration. The report type can be set in Seller Central > Settings 
> Checkout Pipeline Settigns >
Order Reports.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Bck.
Actually i want to get XML response For Reports API(GetReport Operation).
You have mentioned about Order Reports.Please Tell me about Reports API(GetReport operation)